# How to to stop footer moving together with download button when mouse hovers on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".download").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".download").css("margin-top", "32px");
    $(".footer").css("margin-top", "18px;");
  });
  $(".download").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".download").css("margin-top", "30px");
    $(".footer").css("margin-top", "20px;");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
  background: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.video {
  width: 560px;
  height: 315px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 105px;
}

.download {
  width: 850px;
  height: 110px;
  font-size: 33px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.download:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.footer {
  width: 154px;
  height: 27px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.footertext {
  width: 600px;
  height: 46px;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.microsoft-cortana.com/forward.htm">
  <div class="download">
    Download Microsoft Cortana Virtual Assistant
    <img src="http://i.hizliresim.com/xJ9OyE.png" style="margin:auto; margin-top:7px; width:200px;display:block" />
  </div>
</a>




<div class="footer">
  <a href="privacy.htm">Privacy</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="terms.htm">Terms</a>
</div>



<div class="footertext">
  Microsoft Cortana is the Windows Phone intelligent personal assistant on Windows Phone 8.1 operating system. Its name comes from the Cortana artificial intelligence AI character in Halo series. Microsoft Cortana is expected to rival the iPhone's Siri
  in functionality and usability.
</div>
```

I want only the download button to move when the mouse hovers on it. But somehow the footer moves with it too on hover.

How can I fix this?

Comment: **Using only CSS** http://jsfiddle.net/nTL9e/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than adding margin, which is pushing the footer down, why not just use position?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".download").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".download").css("top","32px");
    });
    $(".download").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".download").css("top","0");
    });
});
```

Then add

```
.download{
    position: relative;
}
```

Full snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".download").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".download").css("top", "32px");
  });
  $(".download").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".download").css("top", "0");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
  background: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.video {
  width: 560px;
  height: 315px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 105px;
}

.download {
  width: 850px;
  height: 110px;
  font-size: 33px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

.download:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.footer {
  width: 154px;
  height: 27px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.footertext {
  width: 600px;
  height: 46px;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.microsoft-cortana.com/forward.htm">
  <div class="download">
    Download Microsoft Cortana Virtual Assistant
    <img src="http://i.hizliresim.com/xJ9OyE.png" style="margin:auto; margin-top:7px; width:200px;display:block" />
  </div>
</a>




<div class="footer">
  <a href="privacy.htm">Privacy</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="terms.htm">Terms</a>
</div>



<div class="footertext">
  Microsoft Cortana is the Windows Phone intelligent personal assistant on Windows Phone 8.1 operating system. Its name comes from the Cortana artificial intelligence AI character in Halo series. Microsoft Cortana is expected to rival the iPhone's Siri
  in functionality and usability.
</div>
```

Comment: when I hover, it behaves weird, keeps flashing up and down

Comment: That's because of your mouse location...if you position it towards the top, it's going to move down for the mouse enter, but if your cursor is too high, and the mouseout event fires, it will move back up and give you that "flash".

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".download").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".download img").css("margin-top", "32px");
    $(".footer").css("margin-top", "18px;");
  });
  $(".download").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".download img").css("margin-top", "-1px");
    $(".footer").css("margin-top", "20px;");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
  background: black;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.video {
  width: 560px;
  height: 315px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 105px;
}

.download {
  width: 850px;
  height: 110px;
  font-size: 33px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.download:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.footer {
  width: 154px;
  height: 27px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.footertext {
  width: 600px;
  height: 46px;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.microsoft-cortana.com/forward.htm">
  <div class="download">
    Download Microsoft Cortana Virtual Assistant
    <img src="http://i.hizliresim.com/xJ9OyE.png" style="margin:auto; margin-top:7px; width:200px;display:block" />
  </div>
</a>




<div class="footer">
  <a href="privacy.htm">Privacy</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="terms.htm">Terms</a>
</div>



<div class="footertext">
  Microsoft Cortana is the Windows Phone intelligent personal assistant on Windows Phone 8.1 operating system. Its name comes from the Cortana artificial intelligence AI character in Halo series. Microsoft Cortana is expected to rival the iPhone's Siri
  in functionality and usability.
</div>
```

If you have to move Whole image then When SET    .download as Position:relative

Comment: you actually have to move image of Download button